# jQuery Image Rotation Using 'jQueryRotate' plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, plugins

I am trying to make it so that when you hover over a div, it triggers an image to rotate in another div.

I have been trying to use this plugin, http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

Here is my code in a jsFiddle. The green square is rotating using CSS3, however I need to support IE9+ so I need to do it using the jQuery!

The blue square is the one I am trying to animate using jQuery, for the purpose of the example I have just googled a random image, as I read that you cannot rotate a div with jQuery, only images.

http://jsfiddle.net/D6HQR/

I really have no idea what I am doing wrong, could any jQuery wizards please save me!!!!

**UPDATE**

http://jsfiddle.net/HAqQT/

I now have the jQueryRotate plugin working, however it is not working in IE9. The website states that it should work for IE6+

At the moment the blue square is continuously rotating using jQuery, the green square rotates when you hover over the button using CSS3.

Can anyone see a reason why the jQuery wouldn't work in IE9+?

**UPDATE 2**

http://jsfiddle.net/tpHdg/

Code update, blue square now spins when you hover, stops when you hover off.

Still looking for help for IE9 incompatibility.

**Final Update**

Thanks to everyone who helped, in the end I slowly worked my way through it. The reason it wasn't working on IE9 was because of an 'ActiveX Filter' setting, whatever that is....

For now I have a jQuery version working, and the CSS3 version for when it is more supported. If you would like to check out both version here are the links... Feel free to reuse the code if it helps your project!

http://mathewhood.com/misc/css3/rotate/ - CSS3
http://mathewhood.com/misc/js/rotate/ - JS

Thanks again!

Comment: I am not an expert so I can't really help you, but I'm seeing it takes some time for you to get your answer. I suggest you try using firebux, a firefox plug in that can help you with javascript debugging so you can locate your mistakes faster.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have been playing around a bit and have got the jQuery rotate to work but unfortunately it isn't working in IE9 :(

I will update my original post with a new jsFiddle to show this.

Comment: I would like to see your code because I recently had the same question.

Comment: Updated my original post, take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out some code based on the plugin examples:
http://jsfiddle.net/MJyFf/

Ps.: Your revised code is working in IE9.
Ps2.: Hover the blue square on my example

Comment: I checked my code again on IE9, and got a colleague to check. It is not working for either of us on IE9.

You and have arrived at similar code conclusions, I will post mine up also.

I still do not think it is working on IE9 :/

Comment: When I access your jsfiddle link, the blue squeare is rotating. The CSS3 doesn't work but jQuery rotate does.

Comment: Just a hint: in jsfiddle you don't need to inport jquery in your HTML. This can be done on the left sidebar. You can even choose the version you want.

Comment: Oh cool, thanks :) I didn't know that.

Check out the update I just made, similar to yours but a slightly different method (probably worse as I am a rookie haha)

Comment: Actually, mine DOES work in IE9 now, but I had to go Tools -> ActiveX Filtering..

Is that normal?

Comment: Unfortunatly, I can´t answer this with sure. My IE is in default settings for security.